# regular expression for MVC validation

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

What would be the regular expression to find the substrings *`www.`* and *`http://`* in a domain name.

Basically I am writing an MVC validation to disallow a word that includes 
    *`www.`*, *`http://`* or *`http://www.`* in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Regex.IsMatch(myString, @"(www\.|http://)");
```

If you want to specify that they aren't allowed *at the start* of the string, but allow them elsewhere, use:

```
Regex.IsMatch(myString, @"^(www\.|http://)");
```

Comment: I plugged it into the validation and it is returning true no matter what. [RegularExpression(@"(www\.|http://)",ErrorMessage="http:// or www. is not permitted the domain name.")] Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: This is because you need to then assert in your validation that matches are **invalid** but the Regex DataAnnotation asserts that matches are **valid**. Regex is not good at checking that a string "doesn't have a substring" (without horrible lookarounds), so perhaps you could look into implementing a custom validator for `DoesNotMatch`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation.aspx